# How to get SQL Return Code for Ecto Repo.Get call

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I am trying to read a particular row in a postgres table using ecto. The code is something like:

```
Repo.get(LogEntry, id)
```

In the log I am able to see it correctly translated to:

```
SELECT l0."id", l0."view", l0."command", l0."data", l0."authentication_key", l0."signature", l0."prepared", l0."committed", l0."executed", l0."inserted_at", l0."updated_at" FROM "log_entries" AS l0 WHERE (l0."id" = $1) [1]
```

However, though there is a row that matches the criteria in the table the repo.get is returning nil. To understand the reason better, I feel the SQL return code may help. Is there a way to get the SQL return code from ecto?

Comment: Well, what you see in the log is exactly what you are asking for. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you execute that exact SQL, does it return a result?

Comment: @Jose, what I see in the log is the translated sql query. There is no return code

Comment: @christian, the exact sql returns a result when executed directly in pgsql

Comment: You should also see in the log OK or ERROR. If it is OK, it means the query did not fail, it really did not return any result. You can also use `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query/4` to perform queries directly.